# how to convert full date into short type date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I get full date in JavaScript. -> "Sun Feb 23 2020 10:12:46 GMT+0800 (CST)"
I'd like to convert this into short date(date type, not string) -> "2020-02-23"
How can I convert this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved, however a simple approach that doesn't require a third-party library would be as follows:

```js
const inputString = "Sun Feb 23 2020 10:12:46 GMT+0800 (CST)";

/* Parse date object directly from string of supplied format */
const date = new Date(inputString);

/* Define helper function that pads a zero to front on string, if
number less that 10 */
const padNumber = n => `${n < 10 ? '0' : ''}${n}`

/* Format desired output string, and use padNumber help on date parts
as needed */
const outputString = `${date.getFullYear()}-${padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${padNumber(date.getDate())}`

console.log(outputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

its not a build in function but you can always

iterate the string until the first number comes.

you start recording a 'date' string then,

then replace the whitespaces with dashes

and stop recording your date string at the first ':'

you could make a function out of this, or search for a built-in

Comment: You could provide with an example code, it would be a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

You  can use a moment package to fulfil your purpose. Here is the small example.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dateText: '',
    };
  }

    onDOBDatePicked = (date) => {
      this.setState({
        dateText: moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
      });
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      const date = "Sun Feb 23 2020 10:12:46 GMT+0800 (CST)";
      this.onDOBDatePicked(date);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ padding : 50 }}>
          {this.state.dateText}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```